# How to get the <strong> next of double quotes values on dom element php

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, element

i want to **scrape** the pages but In  that pages they provide values like that below, but i take  element using elementby Tagname and i cant take doubt quotes values next of strong tag, can anyone please help me.

```
<br>
<br>
<strong>Location</strong>
"India,calculata
"
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i am tried curl function using dom document in  php and i tried the sample code as here  $table = $dom->getElementById('JobDesc3606816961');
    foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('strong') as $tablelist)
    {$tablelist->nodeValues} to get response of strong tag values and all but i need next of strong tag values example of above, i used strong tag to get Location name but  I need values of India and calculata

Comment: if you want *India,calculata*, grab the parent element which wraps it, then remove the junk from inside it, your need do some tweaking as its not a nice structured DOM.. i.e: https://3v4l.org/3KV2l

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response.nodevalues contains all the values, how to split it country,city and all$table = $dom->getElementById('JobDesc3606816961') foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tablelist)
{ echo $tablelist->textContent."\n";} i get overall values of country:india city:Delhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current code (from comment), you just need to change from accessing the current elements value to the next child value (using `nextSibling`)...

```
$table = $dom->getElementById('JobDesc3606816961'); 
foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('strong') as $tablelist) {
    echo $tablelist->nextSibling->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nigel,lawrence and jay, issues as solved